# merging 2 dataframes in pandas using 1 to supply missing values for the other

Tags: pandas

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes.  They look like this:

```
df1 =
          e   u
0  0.095473   1
1  0.275177   3
2  0.239138   5
3  0.123721   7
4  0.033521   9
5  0.007609  11
6  0.001542  13

df2 =
          e   u
0  0.239847   5
1  0.145069   7
2  0.047716   9
3  0.011630  11
4  0.002493  13
```

I want a dataframe that has the values from df2, but using df1 to supply the missing
values.  The 'index' is 'u'.  As you see, df2 has the same 'u' values as df1, but some are
missing (df1 has 1,3,5,7,9,11,13 which df2 has 5,7,9,11,13).

Answer (score 1):

First set your indexes to u then update df1 with df2

```
df1 = df1.set_index('u')
df2 = df2.set_index('u')

df1.update(df2)#does update in place does not return a copy
print df1
```

**output of df1 is now....**

```
           e
u
1   0.095473
3   0.275177
5   0.239847
7   0.145069
9   0.047716
11  0.011630
13  0.002493
```